# List of directory names without the path?

Tags: macos, find

I'm looking to get the name of a bunch a directories at a specified level.

This is what I've got so far:

```
find . -type d -depth 2 -print
```

But this also prints the relative path of these directories. How can I just get their name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type d -depth 2 -printf '%f\n'
```

From the [GNU findutils manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Name-Directives.html#Name-Directives):

> `%f` File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element).

Edit: In the lack of the `-printf` action, try this:

```
find . -type d -depth 2 -exec basename '{}' ';'
```

Comment: Just forgot to say that i'm on Mac OSX. find doesn't have -printf option.